# Mef import into objects created after compose

Tags: mef, composition

I Compose the Container at startup and later on create a Instance of a object that has a Import property. This property is Null when I try to use it.

How does MEF handle objects created later on. I refuse to believe you have to instantiate all objects at startup.

Comment: OK I think I'm possibly misunderstanding how MEF sets up. The Catalogs look only for Exports I guess and I need to create a batch. I have a hard time figuring out how to construct a system from bottom up. any good tutorials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to create instances as soon as you create the container, that wouldn't be any real help for anyone. How are you creating your instances? Here are some examples, given an example class:

```
[Export]
public class MyClass
{
    [Import]
    public MyOtherClass OtherClass { get; set; }
}
```

I could:

```
var myClass = container.GetExportedValue<MyClass>(); // This would automatically compose.

var myExport = container.GetExport<MyClass>();
var myClass = myExport.Value; // This would automatically compose.

var myClass = new MyClass();
container.SatisfyImportsOnce(myClass); // Manually compose your part.
```

Or manually wind it all together using a `CompositionBatch`, etc.

Comment: So do you propagate your container down through all classes to have access when you need to compose a new import?